# Dialogbox after ListView sends Enter to ListView

Tags: .net, listview

I have a listview which happens to react to pressing the `Enter` or `Return` key. There is also a contextmenu on items. One to the menu entries opens a dialog box. When I enter something in that dialog box and press enter the dialogbox accepts the value and closes. So far everything good.

But the `Enter`/`Return` from that dialogbox is *send back* to the listview where the `KeyUp` event starts. That is not intended!

Additional information: The dialogbox sets a button as `AcceptButton` so that pressing `Enter` in that form will automatically fire that button which itself closes the dialog with a `DialogResult`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I changed to use the `KeyDown` event on the listbox insted of `KeyUp` and do no longer have the problem (as keydown is in dialogbox and not on listview, but keyup occurs on listview).